Azure Machine learning studio gives an error File https://aka.ms/bike-rentals/MLTable is empty
I am following these https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/01-machine-learning.html instructions to train a model in Azure Machine learning studio.  I followed the instructions exactly however I get the following error File https://aka.ms/bike-rentals/MLTable is empty. Please make sure it's a valid MLTable which must match the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-data?tabs=uri-file-example%2Ccli-data-create-example#uris). If you want to proceed, consider checking "Skip data validation" and click "Next." We will not validate your data path or query, or try to access your data for preview and schema checks.  I have tried to upload from blobstorage and that doesn't work either. Any thoughts
I was expecting the data set would be uploaded

You need to alter MLTable file accordingly. please check the documentaion and try again with new MLTable file.

What files you are uploading?

When you give the data type as mltable you should be having a file called MLTable which contains the details of your dataset like path, type of file, headers etc.
After downloading and unzipping the file, you will get 2 files both needs to be uploaded.
one csv and other is MLTable with below content.
# MLTable definition file

paths:
  - file: ./daily-bike-share.csv
transformations:
  - read_delimited:
        delimiter: ','
        encoding: 'ascii'

Here, path for you dataset file and delimiter is given. You can also give the header, column transformation etc details.
I have tried in my environment and it is working fine.

Make sure you are given right path to your dataset file.
Data preview

check this stack solution also.

Also note extracting the folder creates a nested folder with the same name. Be sure to drill into the second folder at the extraction path: bike-data\bike-data to select the leaf folder, to select it, otherwise you may get the same error.
